# Does filtering order affect query results in Firestore?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I have a query to get some Firestore data using the where clause. (I'm using *angularfire2*)

**Code:**

```
this.db.collection('trips', ref => ref.where('origin', '==', this.trip.origin)
                                  .where('destination', '==', this.trip.destination)
                                  .where('avaiableSeats', '>', 0))
```

The problem I have is that for the same data, **that query does not return anything**.

But if I change *origin* for *destination* like this:

```
this.db.collection('trips',ref=>ref.where('destination', '==', this.trip.destination)
                                  .where('origin', '==', this.trip.origin)
                                  .where('avaiableSeats', '>', 0))
```

Suddenly, all objects are returned properly. Any idea why or what is happening?